# Proof for $\forall x \in [0, \frac{\pi}{2}]\quad \sin(x) \ge \frac{x}{2}$

Tags: calculus, geometry, trigonometry, inequality

What is the proof for $\forall x \in [0, \frac{\pi}{2}]\quad \sin(x) \ge \frac{x}{2}$ ?
Assuming it is true.

Comment: Sorry! I corrected the equation (instead of $\frac{\pi}{2}$ it is now $\frac{x}{2}$)

Comment: See also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/980551/sin-x-geq-frac2x-pi-x-in-0-frac-pi2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

let $$\widehat{KOA}=x$$
the area of parallel sides kA'OA $=\sin x$

the area of Circular sector $=\frac{1}{2}x$

so you can see that the area of Circular sector < the area of parallel sides

$$\Rightarrow\sin x >\frac{1}{2}x $$

Comment: I think this becomes a little more obvious if we use $AK$ rather than $OK$ as the diagonal of the parallelogram, so that the parallelogram completely contains the circular sector.

Answer (score 5):

Well, simply study the variations of $f(x)=\sin(x)-\dfrac{x}{2}$ : compute $f'$, solve $f'(x)=0$, study the sign of $f'$ and so on...

Comment: Thanks :) Do you have that in trigonometry as well?

Answer (score 2):

the graph of $y = f(x) = \sin x$ is concave down on $[0,\pi/2], $ therefore $ \sin x \ge \dfrac{2x}{\pi} > \dfrac{x}{2}$  on $0 \le x \le \pi/2.$

**edit:** I used that the secant line $y = 2x/\pi$ is below the graph $y = \sin x$ on the interval $0 \le x \le \pi/2$.

Answer (score 1):

When $0\leq x\leq{\pi\over2}$ then $\cos{x\over2}\geq{1\over\sqrt{2}}$ and therefore
$$\sin x=2\cos{x\over2}\sin{x\over2}=2\cos^2{x\over2}\tan{x\over2}\geq\tan{x\over2}\geq{x\over2}\ .$$

Answer (score 1):

From the figure:

Arc$(AX)=x \Rightarrow $  area-sector$(OAX)=x/2$

$ AB=OA=1 \Rightarrow $ area-triangle$(OXB)= \sin x$.

So we can simply see the statement.

[image]

Comment: Could you please clarify regarding area-sector$(OAX)=x/2$ ?

Comment: The area of the circle is $\pi^2r=2\pi r^2/2$. Note that $2\pi r$ is the length of the entire circumference, so, for an arc of length $x$ we have area-sector=$xr/2$, and as $r=1$...