# Prove that 2/π ≤(sinx)/x ≤ 1 for all |x|≤ π/2.

Tags: real-analysis

Real Analysis
Prove that 2/π ≤(sinx)/x ≤ 1 for all |x|≤ π/2 ? Just need the 2/π greater than part.

Comment: Hint: convexity

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/980551/how-to-show-sin-x-geq-frac2x-pi-x-in-0-frac-pi2?noredirect=1&lq=1 https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1126449/proof-for-forall-x-in-0-frac-pi2-quad-sinx-ge-fracx2?noredirect=1&lq=1 https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/407517/the-sine-inequality-frac2-pi-x-le-sin-x-le-x-for-0x-frac-pi2?noredirect=1&lq=1 https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/213382/prove-an-inequality-with-a-sin-function-sinx-frac2-pi-x-for-0x-fr?noredirect=1&lq=1https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2029743/show-that-x-sin-frac-pi-x2-forall-x-in-0-1?noredirect=1

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

On the interval $\bigl[0,\frac\pi2\bigr]$, the sine function is concave. As a consequence, the slopes of the chords joining  a point of the curve to the origin are *decreasing*, and $\frac2\pi$ is the slope of the chord joining the local maximum $\bigl(\frac\pi2,1\bigr)$ to the origin.

Comment: You mean that in the interval the slope of any point on sine curve (that is cosx ) is greater than the chord with slope 2/π.How are you then getting it in sinx / x form ? Integration of cosx < 2/π ? Sounds correct but I am looking for a solution based on monotonicity of functions. Thank you.

Comment: The slope of the *chord* joining the origin to another point (or any fixed point to another point on its right), not the slope of the tangent.

Comment: That is fine but how is that leading up to 2/π ≤ sin(x) / x ?

Comment: $\sin x/x$ is the slope of the chord joining the point with abscissa $x$ to the origin. It decreases down to its value at $\frac\pi2$.

Comment: Alright got it ! Thank you.

Comment: Don't forget to prove it is decreasing.

Comment: I did it using g(x)=xcos(x)- sin(x) being decreasing and g(0)=0.

Comment: Perfect! Actually this would be valid for any  concave function (even non-differentiable) – as far as I remember, it is an exercise in Michael Spivak's *Calculus*.

Answer (score 0):

We can assume that $$0<x\le \frac{\pi}{2}$$ since $$\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$$ is even.
We multiply by $x>0$ and we have to prove that $$\frac{2}{\pi}x\le\sin(x)\le x$$.
Defining $$f(x)=x-\sin(x)$$ then we get $$f'(x)=1-\cos(x)>0$$ and let
$$g(x)=\sin(x)-\frac{2}{\pi}x$$ then we get $$g'(x)=\cos(x)-\frac{2}{\pi}$$ and $$g''(x)=-\sin(x)<0$$
Can you finish?

Comment: Sir, I did something similar. Unlike the f(x) function, g(x) is not strictly monotonic. It is changing slope at x= cos–¹(2/π). Also, please explain a bit more on how to get  2/π xsinx ≤ x ?