# A geometric proof for the inequality $\frac{2x}{\pi} \le \sin(x)$

Tags: trigonometry, inequality

The inequality $\frac{2x}{\pi}\le \sin(x)\le x$ for $0 \le x\le \frac \pi 2$ is well known; it can be proved using calculus.

The second part can be proved for $x\in [0,\pi/2]$ by geometric arguments:

> Take unit circle with center origin. Then compare areas of (sector with angle $x$) and (right angled triangle with height $\sin x$).

**Q.** Can we prove $\frac{2x}{\pi}\le \sin(x)$ for $x\in [0,\pi/2]$ by geometric arguments?

**Note:** There are proof of first inequality are available using calculus, but I want to know if there is a proof, not based on calculus (Rolle's theorem, or mean value theorem etc.), but with some basic geometric arguments as done in the proof of $\sin(x)\le x$.

Comment: Does this http://www.stumblingrobot.com/2015/12/19/prove-the-inequality-2x-sin-x-x-for-0-x-2/ clarify your question

Comment: There is a “geometric proof” in this Wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan%27s_inequality

Comment: @Martin: This is nice proof. +1

Comment: I have taken the liberty to edit the question title. I have tried to state more precisely what you are looking for. Feel free to revert the change or edit it again if that does not match your intentions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is taken from [Wikipedia: Jordan's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan%27s_inequality) where it is attributed to

- Yuefeng, Feng. “Proof without Words: Jordan's Inequality 2x/π ≤ Sin x ≤ x, 0 ≤ x ≤π/2.” Mathematics Magazine, vol. 69, no. 2, 1996, pp. 126–126. JSTOR, https://www.jstor.org/stable/2690669.

[image]

(File: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Jordans_inequality.svg, Attribution: Kmhkmh, CC BY 3.0 https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0, via Wikimedia Commons.)

The arc from $C$ to $D$ on the unit circle has the length $x$, and the arc from $G$ to $D$ on the circle with radius $\sin(x)$ has the length $\frac \pi 2 \sin(x)$. It follows that
$$
x \le \frac \pi 2  \sin(x) \iff \frac 2 \pi x \le  \sin(x) \, .
$$

Answer (score 0):

Let
$$f(x)=\sin x-\frac{2x}{\pi},x\in[0,\pi/2].$$
Then $$f''(x)=-\sin x\leq 0,x\in[0,\pi/2],$$
which implies $f(x)$ is concave function.

> $\textbf{Concavity implies the function is above the secant line.}$

Due to $f(0)=f(\pi/2)=0$, we can get
$$f(x)\geq tf(0)+(1-t)f(\pi/2)=0,x\in[0,\pi/2].$$

Comment: From the question: *“There are proof of first inequality are available using calculus, but I want to know if there is some geometric arguments.”*

Comment: Is "concavity" not  geometric arguments? concavity implies the function is above the  secant line!

Comment: Perhaps I am interpreting the question differently, I expected something using triangles in the unit circle, similar to the example given in the question. Otherwise we could close the question as a duplicate of e.g. this one https://math.stackexchange.com/a/980553.

Comment: @Martin: I added something in the note, which will little clarify my question. Let me know if the question (or note) is ok now.